# Creating GUI in JFrame to do bubble, insertion and quick sort and add code to action performed

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe

I am new to Java. I am to use JFrame to to create a GUI with a Sort menu option and items include (Bubble, Insertion, Quick sort). I am also to use the action performed event that is automatically created in the JFrame, to input my code so to have the numbers be sorted according to the sort selection. When the user inputs not more than 10 integers in a textField and bubble sort is selected, the result should be displayed in a JLabel. I have run my code with no error however, my result does not appear in the label. Can anyone help as to what may be coded wrongly? See below my code for the bubble selection.

```
private void jMenu1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
         // TODO add your handling code here:
         int c, n, d, swap;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n=in.nextInt();

        int array[] = new int[n];
        for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
      {
        array[c]= in.nextInt();

       for(c=0;c < (n-1);c++)
      {
          for (d=0; d < n-c-1;d++)
          {
          if(array[d]>array[d+1])
          {
              swap=array[d];
              array[d]=array[d+1];
              array[d+1]=swap;
          }
      }
      }
      for ( c=0;c<n;c++)
      {
         jTextArea1.setText(Integer.toString(array[c])); 
                 //Integer.toStri

      }

    }                                      

    }
```

Comment: Don't mix console input with gui input.  Either provide a panel/form which has 10 `JTextField`'s on it or use a `JTable` to gather the user input (although I might also recommend using `JSpinner`s instead).  Use `JTextArea#append` over `JTextArea#setText`...

Comment: I am to have one text field where users can input maximum of ten numbers to sort and one label to display the result of the sorted numbers in either ascending order or descending order.

Comment: Are you taking the input in as a whole or as single elements?

Comment: So each time the user enters something into the text field and presses [Enter] (or some other button) the value needs to be added to your `array`...?

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: The user enters integers { 5 8 7 9 0} in the text field, they should go to the sort option on the menu and for instance select bubble sort, the result of the bubble sort {0 5 7 8 9} should be displayed in a label.

Comment: I have ran the program from the main class.java and it ran perfectly, whereby it request the integers and displays the result on the console via bubble sort however i am unable to run it whenever i use the drag and drop in JFrame.

Answer (score 1):

I hope my sample will help you even though I took some personal decisions since it wasn't all crystal clear. Anyway let me make some precisions : by default it will call bubble sort if you don't choose anything from the sorting menus and click directly on launch. Moreover, the checkbox if it's selected will try to compute ascending order which means descending if it's not.

For the isSortable() method, well, you mentionned a condition about 10 numbers which I included in my code but, I don't know which condition you wanted exactly so I implemented a return true method which I'll let you complete, same for the algorithms, I explicitely put default values to check the GUI was ok. 
As for the separator, well I assumed you wanted to managed only integers and separated by "," so, again if you want to enrich it :) !

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Sorter extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5548803322850070957L;
    private static final String BUBBLE_SORT = "bubble sort";
    private static final String INSERTION_SORT = "insertion sort";
    private static final String QUICK_SORT = "quick sort";
    private static final String SEPARATOR = ",";
    private static final String NO_RESULT = "no result";

    private static final Dimension TEXT_INPUT_DIM = new Dimension(200, 30);

    private static final JMenuBar MENU = new JMenuBar();
    private static final JMenu SORT = new JMenu("Sorting Algorithms");
    private static final JMenuItem BUBBLE = new JMenuItem(BUBBLE_SORT);
    private static final JMenuItem INSERTION = new JMenuItem(INSERTION_SORT);
    private static final JMenuItem QUICK_S = new JMenuItem(QUICK_SORT);

    private final JTextField textfieldInput = new JTextField();
    private final JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();
    private final JLabel orderLabel = new JLabel("sort in ascending order");

    private final JLabel labRes = new JLabel("sorted result : ");
    private final JLabel res = new JLabel(NO_RESULT);

    private static String selectedMenu;

    public Sorter() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        textfieldInput.setPreferredSize(TEXT_INPUT_DIM);

        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        top.setLayout(new FlowLayout(10));
        top.add(textfieldInput);
        top.add(createPanelCheckbox());
        top.add(createSortButton());
        add(top);

        add(createPanelResult());
    }

    private Component createSortButton() {
        JButton sortButton = new JButton("Launch");
        sortButton.addActionListener(this);
        return sortButton;
    }

    private final JPanel createPanelResult() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(labRes, BorderLayout.WEST);
        p.add(res, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return p;
    }

    private final JPanel createPanelCheckbox() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new FlowLayout(10));
        p.add(checkbox);
        p.add(orderLabel);
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(500, 300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(new Sorter());
        f.setJMenuBar(createMenu());
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static JMenuBar createMenu() {
        BUBBLE.addActionListener(new MenuItemListener());
        SORT.add(BUBBLE);
        INSERTION.addActionListener(new MenuItemListener());
        SORT.add(INSERTION);
        QUICK_S.addActionListener(new MenuItemListener());
        SORT.add(QUICK_S);
        MENU.add(SORT);
        return MENU;
    }

    static class MenuItemListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            selectedMenu = e.getActionCommand();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String content = textfieldInput.getText();
        String[] parsedNumbers = content.split(SEPARATOR);
        if (isSortable(parsedNumbers) && parsedNumbers.length < 10) {
            int[] result = null;

            if(selectedMenu==null)
                selectedMenu = BUBBLE_SORT;

            switch (selectedMenu) {
            case BUBBLE_SORT:
                result = bubbleSort(checkbox.isSelected());
                break;
            case INSERTION_SORT:
                result = insertionSort(checkbox.isSelected());
                break;
            case QUICK_SORT:
                result = quickSort(checkbox.isSelected());
                break;

            }
            res.setText(result == null ? NO_RESULT : fillResultLabel(result));
        }
    }

    private String fillResultLabel(int[] result) {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        for (int nb : result) {
            res.append(nb + " ");
        }
        return res.toString();
    }

    private final boolean isSortable(String[] numbers) {
        return true;
    }

    private int[] bubbleSort(boolean sortAscending) {
        return new int[]{1,2,3,4};
    }

    private int[] insertionSort(boolean sortAscending) {
        return new int[]{5,6,7,8};
    }

    private int[] quickSort(boolean sortAscending) {
        return new int[]{9,10,11,12};
    }
}
```